# Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message (using password: NO)

Tags: c#, mysql

Can you help me guys for my thesis and this is one of my problem in my system.

```
MySqlConnection cn2 = new MySqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString);
cn2.Open();-->>> Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

listView1.Items.Clear();
string sql = "Select * from tblrecord where DateTime between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "'";
cm = new MySqlCommand(sql);
//cm = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn1);
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
if (dr.HasRows)
```

Comment: The problem was in " cn2.Open(); "

Comment: May we see your connection string (I know its private, but I only ask since there is no password in it, according to the error). Or maybe your mysql server has not allowed root access without password yet.

Comment: what should i do to correct it ?

Comment: Go to your mysql server, and create a new user with a password defined by you. Use that user to login from Visual Studio. This is because using root account to login is generally not common, but if you insist, you will need to find out your default root password and use that.

Answer (score 1):

just add password in your connection string because you have not added it in your connction.